# How to remove browser action to repeat handle event earlier?

Tags: asp.net, browser

I have a registration page where I am saving some information. That is running successfully but when I press ctrl +F5 after registration. I get a message by browser to repeat event which is handled earlier. I have done blank all text values and to false viewstate of every control but It is saving 2 times.

Please suggest me. What should I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add a Response.Redirect("/to_a_page.aspx") after you stored all data. That will make sure the page can be refreshed without reposting

Answer (score 0):

The strategy here is to call `Response.Redirect("SamePage.aspx").`

Comment: I already know this solution. But I want to know another better solution

Comment: Then state that in your question.